why the C++ app crashes when running again updated shared library
I create a dummy c++ app:
---->libmars.so:
---->mars.h:
#ifndef mars_h__ 
#define mars_h__
class AAA {
public:
    AAA();
};

#endif  // mars_h__`
   

--->main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mars.h"

AAA::AAA()
{
    puts("I am in mars ctor()");
}

g++ -g -std=c++11 -shared -o libmars.so -fPIC mars.cpp

--->main app:
#include "mars.h"
int main(void)
{
    AAA a;
}

g++ -g  -L./ -Wl,-rpath=./ -o mars main.cpp -lmars
./mars

I am in mars ctor()
<<<<no crash, the mars1 runs OK, now I update the libmars.so:
---->mars.h:
#ifndef mars_h__
#define mars_h__

class AAA {
    int nopages[4]={1,2,3,4};
public:
    AAA();
    ~AAA();
};

#endif  // mars_h__

---->mars.cpp:
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "mars.h"
AAA::AAA()
{
    puts("I am in mars ctor()\n");
}
AAA::~AAA()
{
    puts("I am in mars dtor()\n");
}

g++ -g -std=c++11 -shared -o libmars.so -fPIC mars.cpp

Note: I did not rebuild the app mars, only build the updated libmars.so:
./mars

I am in mars ctor()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
If rebuild mars:
g++ -g  -L./ -Wl,-rpath=./ -o mars main.cpp -lmars
./mars

I am in mars ctor()
I am in mars dtor()
nocrash if rebuilt. I understand it will not crash when rebuilt, we had a situation to maintain/update a few shared libs, but we do not rebuilt the app which dependent on those libs.
the question is why add a member variable to the updated class will crash the app.
I use the following version of the app, no crash:
int main(void)
{
    AAA *a = new AAA();
    delete a;
    a = nullptr;
}

./mars:

I am in mars ctor()
but it did not call the destructor.

Here's a nice list of things you can and can't do to maintain binary compatibility: https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B

The class size and layout is different leading to mismatch - an ABI mismatch. You don't change users' headers when updating shared libraries unless you expect users to recompile their code.

"why add a member variable to the updated class will crash the app" - There are two different definitions of AAA in the program. See One Definition Rule

"why add a member variable to the updated class will crash the app" It should be kinda obvious. The application believes the size of the class is X, and allocates that much space for it on the stack. But the library believes the size is Y > X, and initializes Y bytes on the stack - scribbling over whatever happens to be there right after the class instance. In your example, it's probably the return address that gets overwritten by garbage.

For shared libraries do not expose any implementation details. E.g. do not export classes, but export pure abstract baseclasses with methods that only use standard C++ types for their arguments (or header file only structs composed of such types). And provide factory methods to make instances (of implementation) inside the dll. Then as long as C++ versions are ABI compatible things should be fine.

"but it did not call the destructor." In the declaration the application sees, there's no destructor to call (or to be precise, there's a trivial no-op destructor that can be optimized away).

You added this to the class int nopages[4]={1,2,3,4}; which will change its size in memory. The "old" client code was compiled not knowing these members are there. So it assumes a smaller memory size and gets into all kind of memory managment issues. It is for reasons like this "interfaces" (abstract baseclasses) and the pimpl patten exist.  Make sure you have a compilation firewall that allows you to change implementation without affecting the interface of the dll.

You have broken binary compatibility of your dynamic library. To limit problems of this kind, PImpl pattern can be used. Note it will solve problems with changing list if member variables, other binary compatibility issues can't be resolved this way.
